# What is wrong with my overloaded operator<< function?

Tags: linked-list, operator-overloading

```
ostream & operator<<(ostream &out, const IntList &rhs)
{
    IntNode *i = rhs.head;
    out << rhs.head;
    while (rhs.head != 0)
    {
        out << " " << i;
        i = rhs.head->next;
    }

    return out;
}
```

The program compiles successfully but does not print anything out. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `i` instead of `rhs.head`

```
 while (i != 0)
 {
   out << " " << i;
   i = i->next;
 }
```

`rhs.head != 0` can't be changed by what's in the loop, so if it's false, the loop will never run, if it's true, it will loop forever.

also `i = rhs.head->next;` will always set `i` to the 2nd node (the one after head), not the one after `i`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the input list is empty, therefore `rhs.head != 0` condition fails? Otherwise it would actually result into infinite loop because `rhs.head` is tested instead of `i`. I suppose it should have been:

```
IntNode *i = rhs.head;
out << rhs.head;
while (i != 0) // note the i here
{
    out << " " << i;
    i = i->next; // again i here
}
```

The second question is what is `out` stream because at least head pointer should be printed there...